# How to know if chrome is invoked by cypress

Tags: javascript, cypress

I'm new to Cypress.
I want to set some sample data for e2e testing in application cache only when chrome is invoked by Cypress. Else, normal flow will work.
Is there any way to know if Chrome is invoked by Cypress or not?

Answer (score 1):

When Cypress is automating the browser, it adds a Cypress object to the global object (window in this case)
The way to go here is to add a check like this

```
if (window.Cypress) {
 Write your logic
}
```

Answer (score 1):

There is an object **Cypress.browser** that returns the properties of the browser. You can use this to generate conditions such as:

```
 if (Cypress.browser.name === 'chrome') { ... }
```

There is an expanded explanation found in the documentation -
https://docs.cypress.io/api/cypress-api/browser.html#Conditionals